# Second div goes to the right but stays at the bottom instead of at the top

Tags: html, css, grid

So I am trying to make the second div which is the sidebar, to go to the right of the first div but it stays at the bottom.

```
<div id="content">

     <p class="parleft">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <a href="#" target="_blank">Corrupti fugit laborum consequatur, consectetur magnam nam numquam </a> <b>vitae est debitis sapiente dolorum reprehenderit mollitia aut</b> tempora incidunt, assumenda quam, exercitationem neque.</p>

     <p class="parleft">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti fugit laborum consequatur, consectetur magnam nam numquam vitae est debitis sapiente dolorum reprehenderit mollitia aut tempora incidunt, assumenda quam, exercitationem neque.</p>

     <p id="par3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti fugit laborum consequatur, consectetu.</p>

     <img id="contentimg" src="images/beach-california-dawn-1532771.jpg" alt="California beach" width="275px">

  </div>  <!-- end of content -->

  <div id="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank">Youtube</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.reddit.com/" target="_blank">Reddit</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.udacity.com/" target="_blank">Udacity</a></li>
        </ul>
        <img id="sidebarimg" src="images/beach-california-dawn-1532771.jpg" alt="California beach" width="100px">

  </div>
```

This right here is the css and I added inline-block to the content and sidebar and it does go to the right but then it stays at the bottom.

```
#content {
width: 696px;
background-color: rgb(221, 86, 86);
display: inline-block;
}

#sidebar{
width: 196px;
background-color: rgb(93, 93, 238);
text-align: left;
display: inline-block;

}
```

Comment: you are using fixed width, are you aware about?

Comment: Yes I am aware.

Comment: ok, miss understood the question .. thought it wasn't on the right and going to the bottom

Answer (score -1):

float the first div to the left

```
#content {
float: left;
width: 696px;
background-color: rgb(221, 86, 86);
display: inline-block;
}
```

you may also have to adjust the width so the second div can contain the remaining space after floating